# php: How to save the client socket (not closed), so a further script may retrieve it to send an answer?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a client-server application, in which the server may require to send information back to clients.

As the client-server pattern does not allow the server to "request" the client, there are 2 solutions:

- The client pull the server every few time (which is a bad solution)
- The client maintain an open socket with the server, that allow the server to send new information back when required.

Currently, the client (Web app with JavaScript and Html/Css) open a streaming connection to the server (A C++ server) which may send information back to the client.

I would like to implement a PHP version of this feature to allow low-cost hosting to work with my program (low-cost hosting usually does not provide access to install/run binaries).
The idea is that the client make a request that establish the streaming socket, it save the socket and then, an other request may retrieve this socket and send new information through it.

So, my question is:
How to save an http socket in PHP, so a further request may retrieve it?

- How to finish the PHP script without closing the socket?
- How to save socket information?
- How to retrieve the socket from a new thread/request?

I do not know even if that is possible, I read about pfsockopen, but it seem a bit different to what I need ( I may be wrong ).

[image]

Comment: Websockets will be your answer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to convert (for example apache-httpd) socket to websockets?

Comment: php shouldn't finish, if you want to leave socket open... so while(true) with sleep is answer..

Comment: `other request may retrieve this socket` - no, you can't it... your client already comes to new connection...

Comment: think about workflow without sockets... You can just store some 'sessions' identified by any client-related tokens...

Comment: @vp_arth I may get the PHP thread open with a while/sleep, but how an others PHP threads may contact this one to send information? If there is no sharing of socket and no communication between threads, the last solution is PHP pulling against a database, which is as bad as the client pulling.

Comment: php can make database query for new data, for example... On shared hostings you have not any flexability... may be some local unix sockets may be used as input also.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php#86667

Comment: I would think that trying to get such an app to run on low-cost hosting may be a bit of a now starting.  You will basically need to daemonize PHP, which is probably not going to be allowed on a lot of these systems.

Comment: Would your low-cost hosting allow to execute command line php?

Comment: @Marek, It is not "my" hosting, but any hosting that would use my library. So the answer is maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need two connections for each client, one persist for get data from server, and other to send data to.

Something like:

in persist.php:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server('unix:///tmp/unique.sock', $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    $buffer = "";
    // Read until double CRLF
    while( !preg_match('/\r?\n\r?\n/', $buffer) )
        $buffer .= fread($client, 2046); 

    //Operate with our listener
    echo $buffer;
    flush();

    // Respond to socket client
    fwrite($conn,  "200 OK HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
```

in senddata.php:

```
$sock = stream_socket_client('unix:///tmp/unique.sock', $errno, $errstr);
fwrite($sock, $data);
fflush($sock);
fclose($sock);
```

Comment: Your solution using unix socket between php threads seem to work, but persist.php should create a stream_socket_server, not just connect to an existing one, shouldn't?

Comment: Yes, sure. I never use it, so, I write only to think direction.

Comment: I modify answers, using HTTP like protocol.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it - forget about `sockets`.

Pseudocode:

```
// receive request, set some session_id if not exists
// request contains last_timestamp, so we know which data client already have
// check have we any dataset for this session_id after last_timestamp
// return this dataset, or no_new_data signature
```

Data can be stored in database, for example.